# Using both boost::bind and std::tr1::bind in different parts of the client code

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, stdbind

I am using two custom libraries that use the bind functionality.
One of them uses the bind functionality present in std::tr1 while the other uses boost bind

Now the problem is with respect to the placeholders. Since boost bind's placeholders are in an unnamed namespace I face the following error when I try to compile my code

```
<file_name.cpp:line_no:char_no>: error: reference to '_1' is ambiguous
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/functional:859:23: error: candidates are: std::tr1::_Placeholder<1> std::tr1::placeholders::{anonymous}::_1
<path>/common/include/boost/bind/placeholders.hpp:55:15: error:                 boost::arg<1> {anonymous}::_1
```

Attaching just the line that uses the boost bind functionality from the client code that I am using

```
f_args.f_cb = boost::bind(&MyProcess::flush, MyProcess::Type, _1, _2);
```

How can one solve the issue? The possibility of making changes to the library or using a different one are ruled out for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholders in the final `std` are identified by traits classes.

Instead of `using namespace` the placeholders, use the traits class to make boost placeholders into `std` placeholders.

If that is not practical, the same is probably true of your boost placeholders: create a new set of placeholder tokens for both, and use those instead for both.

Comment: The namespace is included in the library header files.

Comment: @rgk: are you saying, that you have a `using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;` statement in your headerfile?

Comment: @rgk ok.  How about paragraph 3?  Create new placeholders (either variables of the same type, or use traits classes to mark other types as placeholder variables) and use those.

Comment: @MikeMB Its in the library header file not mine.

Comment: @Yakk I am not sure what you mean. Can you please give an example?

Comment: @rgk The variable `_1` is a variable of a particular type.  Create another variable of the same type with a different name, say `one`.  Use it in place of `_1` so there isn't an ambiguity.  There are also ways to mark up particular type as placeholder types (at least in production `std`), but that isn't required to solve your problem.  Do this for both `std::tr1` and `boost`, and give the two variables different names.